# While trying to scrape the data from the website it is displaying none as the "output"

Tags: web-scraping

Link of the website: https://awg.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/AW/job/Lincoln/Business-Analyst_R15025-2
how to get the location, job type , salary details from the website.

Can you please help me in locating the above mentioned details in the HTML code using Beautifulsoup.
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaK1l.png)

Comment: could just be a problem with the server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The site uses a backend api to deliver the info, if you look at your browser's Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR and refresh the page you'll see the data load via json in a request with a similar url to the one you posted.

So if we edit your URL to be the same as the backend api url then we can hit it and parse the JSON. Unfortunately the pay amount is buried in some HTML within the JSON so we have to get it out with BeautifulSoup and a bit of regex to match the £###,### pattern.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://awg.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/AW/job/Lincoln/Business-Analyst_R15025-2'
search = 'https://awg.wd3.myworkdayjobs.com/wday/cxs/awg/AW/'+url.split('AW')[-1] #api endpoint from Developer Tools
data = requests.get(search).json()

posted = data['jobPostingInfo']['startDate']
location = data['jobPostingInfo']['location']
title = data['jobPostingInfo']['title']

desc = data['jobPostingInfo']['jobDescription']
soup = BeautifulSoup(desc,'html.parser')
pay_text = soup.text
sterling = [x[0] for x in re.findall('(\£[0-9]+(\,[0-9]+)?)', pay_text)][0] #get any £###,#### type text

final = {
    'title':title,
    'posted':posted,
    'location':location,
    'pay':sterling
}

print(final)
```